# AJAX Appending instead of using .HTML for my chat

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So basically, my chat right now works like this:

- Every 2nd second it checks for my PHP file, loadchat.php.
- Loadchat.php will get every row that is newer than their session.
- It then replaces all current data in my div: #chatbox by using
  .html() function.

Now here is the deal.
This seems very resource heavy, to load all the rows again and again and again.
I know there is a way to optimize this, by using .append() function.

All though, I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

I need to make some kind of a counter, or a timestamp when the last message was loaded to check if there is newer content (rows) than since last time it loaded, if there is, append that new content.

If I replace the .html function with .append, I will just keep getting the same messages over and over again, as right now.

How would I go about making this?

Thanks in advance.

```
//AJAX Timeout Loop Load Chat Function:
function loadChat() {
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax/load_chat.php',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#chatbox').html(data);
      //console.log($('#chatbox')[0].scrollHeight - $('#chatbox').innerHeight());
      //console.log($('#chatbox').scrollTop());
      if(atBottom) {
        $("#chatbox").stop().animate({ scrollTop: $('#chatbox')[0].scrollHeight}, 500);
      }
    },    
  });
}
```

EXAMPLE OF WHAT LOADCHAT WILL SEND BACK:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var imAdmin = true</script>
<div data-chat-sid="76561198216640736" data-chat-msid="76561198216640736" data-chat-sun="deinhoin" class="chat-box__content--single chat-box--mychat">
  <div class="chat-box__content__single--avatar">
     <div class="admin" style="background-image:url(https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/83/83b9e88c1f88451dcc97d2537416bbd413247ad6_full.jpg);"><span>Mod</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="chat-box__content__single--title">deinhoin</div>
  <div class="chat-box__content__single--message">adada</div>
</div>
```

It should only send the var imAdmin variable once. (works with .html()).

Comment: Try making use of the 'data' attribute. You could have something like 'data-timestamp' on each chat item and use that work out what was placed when.

Comment: Can include example of `data` `html` at Question ?

Comment: @AdamJeffers good call, will try working something out with that. guest271314 - There is no need for an example. The appending function willl keep appending messages that are newer than the session, therefor it would keep appending the same messages.

Comment: Cool, nice one, will include some example code in my answer as to how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.slice()`

```js
// `section` : container for chat message elements
var html = $("section div");
// `data` : `html` returned from server
var data = "<div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div>";
// if `data` `.length` greater than existing `section` `div` `.length`,
if ($(data).length > $(html).length) {
  // `.slice()` elements greater than existing `section div` length
  var newdata = $(data).slice($(html).length);
  // append new elements to `section div`
  $("section").append(newdata);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
<div>1</div><div>2</div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Sorry, was about to edit my comment. It inserts the first message, but doesn't insert after that. ._.

Comment: @Dyrhoi _"It inserts the first message, but doesn't insert after that"_ Can include example of `#chatbox` `html` at Question ? , create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: Can't make a JS Fiddle because of the PHP Code I'm using. I can show a gyazo hangon. https://gyazo.com/8fd37f986717e312cba94c54eb5107d4 As you can see, when I input the message, it doesn't load, only when I refresh. EDIT adding php file to OP

Comment: plnkr may allow `php` to run . Adding example of  `#chatbox` `html` to Question may help to determine proper selectors to use . Gist of solution is count how may message elements exist , if `data` contains more chat messages than existing `html` , slice elements greater than existing `html` from `data` , append to `#chatbox` . `php` portion not affect actions in `$.ajax()` `success` . Difficult to try solution without `html` structure

Comment: I've added an example of what Loadchat.php will send back. @guest271314

Comment: @Dyrhoi Is `<script></script>` element actually returned within `data` ?

Comment: Yes it is. @guest271314

Comment: Try adjusting selector to `$("#chatbox .chat-box--mychat").length` to count occurrences of only `.chat-box--mychat`elements

Comment: I did that now, but it acts up weird: example: https://gyazo.com/2296e4b780b0311ae3c4435c8fcbdf13 first message seems to be doubled? :o

Comment: Images not help to determine issue. `if ($(data).find(".chat-box--mychat").length > $(html).find(".chat-box--mychat").length) {}` . If `<script></script>` element only sent once, perhaps send `script` in different process , before `$.ajax()` calls that update message content

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to comply the errors, hence why I use images. Using that nothing works.

Comment: Would you be available to join my join.me. So you could help me directly, instead of waiting for each other replies, would also stop the fail margin. https://join.me/921-646-066

Comment: Like Teamviewer, just browser based.

Comment: Would suggest sending `script` separately , if only called once . Not certain if `$.ajax()` strips `script` tags . Are multiple `.chat-box--mychat` returned within `data` ?

Comment: Are you the one in the Join.me session?

Comment: Yes, have that tab open. A lot of stuff moving around

Comment: You know there is a chat in there right, would be easier probably for you to write there lol ^^

Comment: Not familiar with the site , looks like kaleidoscope of tabs , `js` , `html`

Comment: You're on the join me, just click the chat icon on the top of the site :o?

Answer (score 0):

Try making use of the 'data' attribute. You could have something like 'data-timestamp' on each chat item and use that to work out what was placed when.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: I thought that was a valid answer, I had made the comment already but the OP said he would go that way so thought it was valid. I will include code examples as to how to achieve.